# ruby on rails sunspot solr search show some specific results on top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I'm using Sunspot Solr for indexing and searching in our Rails application

```
search = Product.search do 
            with(:categoery, [1,2,3])
            order_by(:priority)
            #and some other filters
         end
```

But for some specific Users i want to display some product with id suppose [8,9] ordered on-top of search result and then other products(as i don't want to discard other results), is it possible in same search query?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Query Elevation Component](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent) :

> The Query Elevation Component lets you configure the top results for a
>   given query regardless of the normal Lucene scoring. This is sometimes
>   called "sponsored search," "editorial boosting," or "best bets." This
>   component matches the user query text to a configured map of top
>   results.
>
> The text can be any string or non-string IDs, as long as it's indexed.
>   Although this component will work with any QueryParser, it makes the
>   most sense to use with DisMax or eDisMax.
>
> The Query Elevation Component is supported by distributed searching.